# Grails Acegi manual login

Tags: security, authentication, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

Is there a way to do that without using a POST request to "j_spring_security_check"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed the same thing (in my case I wanted to log in a user after they created a new account), so I dug around in the generated RegistrationService and found this is how it is done:

```
import org.springframework.security.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken as AuthToken
import org.springframework.security.context.SecurityContextHolder as SCH

class UserService {
    /** The authentication provider. */
    def daoAuthenticationProvider

    def doLogin(user) {
        // note: must use the unhashed password here
        def token = new AuthToken(user.email, user.password)
        def auth = daoAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(token)
        // log the user in
        SCH.context.authentication = auth
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Note: In my example, I use the email/password to login. The `AuthToken` constructor takes whatever you us as your username/password.

Comment: how i can use a hashed password?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can do that. My first thought is to try and subclass `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, but I'm not sure how far that will get you. What is the use case? Maybe there is another way to do it?

Comment: If you use what I posted on the mailing list it'll work with a hashed password since it doesn't need to call authenticate().